# Autowiring against Interface returns null - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I am working on this `Spring MVC` project where I have trouble getting this `Dao` class auto wired in the controller through an `Interface` that is implemented by the `Dao`. This is portion of my `spring-config.xml`. I am using `aspectJ`, `Annotation` and `TX management`.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.simulator" />
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath*:config.properties" />

<bean id="oidDao" class="com.simulator.service.OidDao">
        <property name="ipaddressNC" value="${ipaddressNC}" />
        <property name="ipaddressOM" value="${ipaddressOM}" />
        </bean>
```

### Dao class:

```
@Component

public class OidDao implements OidManager {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private String ipaddressNC;
    private String ipaddressOM;

    public  String getIpaddressNC() {
        return this.ipaddressNC;
    }

    public  void setIpaddressNC(String ipaddressNC) {
        this.ipaddressNC = ipaddressNC;
    }

    public  String getIpaddressOM() {
        return ipaddressOM;
    }

    public  void setIpaddressOM(String ipaddressOM) {
        this.ipaddressOM = ipaddressOM;
    }
```

### OidManager:

```
public interface OidManager {

    public  String getIpaddressNC();
    public  String getIpaddressOM();
}
```

### Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    OidManager oim;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexpage(ModelMap modelMap) {

        ApplicationContext context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring-config.xml"});
         o = (OidManager)context.getBean("oidDao"); 

       o.getIpaddressNC(); // ---> this returns data read from ext properties file and works fine


                oim.getIpaddressNC(); // ---> this returns null`
```

I am trying to re-use the Dao, hence I dont want to call the ApplicationContext multiple times from each method. What am I doing wrong? If I make the variables `getIpaddressNC, getIpaddressOM` static, then `auto wiring` works, if not `oim` returns null though the `variables` are `initialized via setters` on application load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used both **Component Scanning** and **Manual Wiring** for `OidDao`. You defined `oidDao` in xml config, as follows:

```
<bean id="oidDao" class="com.simulator.service.OidDao">
        <property name="ipaddressNC" value="${ipaddressNC}" />
        <property name="ipaddressOM" value="${ipaddressOM}" />
</bean>
```

Then, added a `Component` annotation on `OidDao`, as follows:

```
@Component
public class OidDao implements OidManager {
...
}
```

Drop the `Component` annotation and you'll be fine, i guess! Because otherwise, `<context:component-scan base-package="com.simulator" />` will pick `OidDao` and instantiate an instance from it with default constructor and without calling your `setters`.

Comment: Excellent. That did the trick. But the setter was  getting called in the dao class and the variable was getting initlaized but somehow when called from controller, it returns null.The value wasn't getting retained in memory.

Comment: Glad it works, i'll appreciate if you vote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using @Component annotation + you have also defined a bean. Therefore actually two beans are created. One created due to use of @Component would have the properties set to 'null'. This is expected since you are not setting the properties to any value. Either remove @Component annotation and use 'autowire-candidate="true"' property on bean definition or else remove the bean definition in XML and use relevant annotation on the class to set properties to correct values from property file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Change your bean definition to:

```
<bean id="oim" class="com.simulator.service.OidDao">
   <property name="ipaddressNC" value="${ipaddressNC}" />
   <property name="ipaddressOM" value="${ipaddressOM}" />
</bean>
```

Let this create bean with id `oim` which can be set to the property `oim` in your Controller.